Splitting data in R by time and occurence of a incident, proportional hazard model
I have a question where I am trying to build a proportional hazard model with a time-varying constant.
Effectively the question is the occurance of an illness following a traumatic event. The traumatic event can happen at any time through the follow up, and I am interested in the increased risk the subjects with the trauma have to the illness compared to those without the trauma history.
The illness has to follow the trauma in time for it to count as a trauma associated illness. I am planning on doing a washout period of 0, then 1 year, 3 years and 5 years (as in if the illness occurs within 1 year etc it would not count as trauma related)
I have a dataframe with
Columns: | ID | Age_at_recruitmen | Age_at_trauma | Age_at_illness | Status | Age_at_censoring_death_end_of_study  |
I have been using tmerge function to try this, but although this splits the data, it makes all the events 0!
Example data:
Outcome_dataset <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  start = c(50, 55, 60),
  stop = c(70, 80, 65),
  event = c(0, 0, 1),  
  Age_at_injury = c(NA, 78, 61),  
)

#EDITED With my code

baseline <- data.frame(
  id = Simple$eid,
  start = Simple$start,
  stop = Simple$stop,
  event = Simple$event
)

injury <- data.frame(
  id = Simple$eid,
  injury_time = Simple$Age_at_injury 
)

# Use tmerge to create the time-varying data
df_tmerge <- tmerge(
  data1 = baseline,
  data2 = baseline,
  id = id,
  tstart = start,
  tstop = stop,
  event = event(event)
)

# Add the injury time-varying exposure
df_tmerge <- tmerge(
  data1 = df_tmerge,
  data2 = head_injury,
  id = id,
  injury = tdc(injury_time)
)

cox_model <- coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, event) ~ injury, data = df_tmerge)
summary(cox_model)

The above code seems to seperate at the time of the event, but not indicate if the subject had the event.
Thanks

Hi DW1310, I have no idea about your problem field and do not know what stsplit in STATA does. From your problem description you present a series of conditions on which you can split/filter the outcome dataset. For a start, start creating a function / combination of the conditions in a separate column. Then think about aggregating the labelled rows for which the condition(s) are met. This is how I approach such problems, if I have not yet a clue on an 'elegant' solution.

I know what you want the final product to look like, based on what's in Outcome_dataset, but getting to there from your original data sounds like the problem.  That makes it hard to help without seeing the original data.  A MWE would help a bunch.  Can you dput() and post a small snippet of your data (or create fake data that has the same key elements as your data)?
